# URL reversion in Django template when pattern name is variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am passing a variable in django template named "link".
This is my code snippet in views.py

```
 link = "msdetail/{{item.post_id}}"
 return render(request, "mart/all-products.html", {'t': ms, 'cat':category, 'link':link})
```

and on html file :

```
<a href={% url '{{link}}' %} class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
```

it is giving this error:

> "NoReverseMatch at /mart/menshirt
>   Reverse for '{{link}}' not found. '{{link}}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.".....

the error happens when i click the button. Can I not pass url like this or is it some other issue?

Comment: Please show your urls.py file containing these url patterns.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
<a href='{{link}}' class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
```

---

#### Why is that?

Typing `{% url 'X' %}` is saying, Get me the `URL` which has `name='X'`.

This is not the case, Your case has a variable that you want to include it in the context, That's all.